# Margin não empurra conteúdo para o centro

Tags: css

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta pois meu margin top não empurrava minha div para baixo, seguindo o exemplo na pergunta anterior consegui resolver, porém agora, utilizando a mesma explicação da pergunta anterior não consigo centralizar meu conteúdo.

```css
.side-menu-user-infos {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
}

.side-menu-user-photo {  
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.side-menu-user-name {
  color: #374147;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu-user-infos">
    <div class="side-menu-user-photo">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="side-menu-user-name">
        Fernando Munhoz
    </div>
</div>
```

Como está ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por qual motivo o meu texto na classe "side-menu-user-name" não se alinha no centro sendo que na classe "side-menu-user-photo" utilizo o margin da mesma forma e o conteudo centraliza??

Comment: Por favor, não remova a edição que adiciona o _snippet_ executável. Ele é recomendado para trechos de código que sejam possíveis de serem executados no lado do cliente (tal como HTML e CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento de classe `side-menu-user-photo` tem uma largura (*width*) definido, diferentemente do `site-menu-user-name`, que não tem uma largura definida explicitamente no seu CSS, o que o faz assumir 100% de largura. Para que o `margin: 0 auto` centralize o elemento em relação ao eixo X, ele deve ter uma largura especificado anteriormente no CSS.

Se você prestar atenção, através das ferramentas de desenvolvedor, poderá perceber que, por ser um elemento *block level* (`display: block` por padrão, já que é uma `div`), o `width` é 100% por padrão. Desse modo, o elemento não será centralizado, por que ele já ocupa o tamanho total no eixo X:

[image: Exemplificação em imagem do parágrafo anterior.]

Como você pode verificar acima, o elemento está centralizado sim! **Na realidade, o que não está centralizado é o texto.** Assim, se você não quiser definir uma largura específica para o `site-menu-user-name`, basta usar o `text-align: center`, que irá alinhar o texto em relação ao eixo X:

```css
.side-menu-user-name {
  color: #374147;
  margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

> Em resumo, ao usar o `margin: 0 auto` para centralizar um elemento, tenha em mente que só irá funcionar caso esse elemento tenha uma largura definida, o que não é o caso do elemento de classe `site-menu-user-name`.

Comment: Obrigado, Luiz.